# Python-sphinx: documentation of a child class won't show when "autodoc_mock_imports" is enabled

Tags: python, gitlab-ci, python-sphinx, autodoc

## Question

Is there a way to generate sphinx documentation of a child class without
installing the library containing its parent class on GitLab CI
(or any comparable CI tool)?

**Edit**: I have 7 such classes and ca. 10 member functions per class on average to be documented. Thus, an automated solution is strongly preferred, as it cost too much time to hard-code the docstrings into the `.rst` files.

If the problem cannot be solved by changing Sphinx settings alone, then I will only accept an answer that provides clear instructions to get the desired documentation generated and published.

## Context

Specifically, I made a child class of `tensorflow.keras.callbacks.Callback`
and want to show its docstring on the documentation page.
By default, Sphinx has to import everything generate documentation. But
it doesn't seem right to install `tensorflow` (and tens of other libraries
that sums up to several GBs) on the CI image just for this. I just want my docstring
to be shown and I don't care about their parent classes. This is the reason
why I turned on `autodoc_mock_imports` in `conf.py` (the Sphinx
configuration file). The docs were build without error, but the documentation
of that child class was missing.

In the MWE below, the customized class is `keras_callback.py`. The sphinx directives is contained in `keras_callback.rst` as follows.

```
.. automodule:: keras_callback

    :members:
    :inherited-members:
```

## Minimum Working Example

There is an [MWE](https://gitlab.com/cbhuang/test-sphinx-mock)
and [Sphinx-generated docs](https://cbhuang.gitlab.io/test-sphinx-mock/keras_callback.html) on my GitLab repo to reproduce the problem.

Desired documentation of the child class looks like this.

[image]

At the minimum, the documentation of my custom function should be shown. Member functions from the parent class can be turned off.

Comment: An option might be to forgo autodoc for this class and instead write the documentation using the `py:class` and `py:method` directives. https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html?highlight=domain#directive-py-class

Comment: OK, I've read that page, but it lacks the context explaining why use it, where to begin with, what to do, and what result should I expect. May you please provide some hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a simple workaround: Build locally and then overwrite the CI-built
page using the locally built page. If the desired page need not rebuild frequently, then this solution may save considerable time hard-coding the members.

## Steps

1. Build locally **without** `autodoc_mock_imports` in `conf.py`.
2. Copy the correct webpage (`keras_callback.html`) to `_static` folder.
3. Re-enable `autodoc_mock_imports`.
4. Add a `cp` command to overwrite the CI-built page in `.gitlab-ci.yml`

> ```
> image: python:3.7-alpine
>
> pages:
> script:
> - pip install sphinx sphinx-rtd-theme recommonmark
> - sphinx-build -d _build/doctrees . _build/html
> - mv _build/html public
> - cp _static/keras_callback.html public
> artifacts:
>     paths:
>     - public
> only:
> - master
> ```

5. Commit, push and check the webpage. Worked for this particular
   MWE (not shown in the repo).

The drawback is of course that the maintainer has to rebuild that page
manually whenever it is updated. But this should suffice for many small
independent projects because docs-publishing usually happens only at
the very end stage of development.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the ["auto" directives](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html?#module-sphinx.ext.autodoc) (such as `automodule` and `autoclass`) that extract documentation from Python code, Sphinx also provides ["non-auto" directives](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#the-python-domain) (`module`, `class` etc.) where all the documentation goes into .rst files.

My suggestion is to replace `.. automodule:: keras_callback` with the following:

```
.. class:: keras_callback.MyKerasCallback
 
   An inherited Keras ``Callback`` class.
 
   .. method:: __init__(dic=None)
 
      Constructor
 
   .. method:: on_epoch_begin(epoch, logs=None)
           
      Inherited method
 
   .. method:: custom_method
 
      Custom method

.. autofunction:: keras_callback.util_func
```

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation. I have 7 such child classes and ca. 10 member functions per class on average. Do I really have to hard-code all of these manually in such a laborious way? I would be very shocked if this is the case. BTW, I will accept this answer if no easier option appears after one week.